# How to make automatic numbering using format A. B. C. in Libre Office Writter?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I want to make this kind of automatic numbering:

A. List item

B. List item

C. List item

It's easy to make it using Microsoft Word.  However, libre office writter seems don't have that style but these:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Choose of the A) or a) numbering format.
2. Select it the numbering or paragraph. Right-click, select Bullets and Numbering -> Alphabet Upper Case List

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

**Note:** This is done from a Windows macine, but I think the steps are the same in Linux.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14. I have following your instruction but "bullets and numbering" in context menu doesn't have multi menu which contain "Alphabet Uppercase List". Does this feature exist on Ubuntu 14?

Comment: What version of LibreOffice are you using?

Comment: I'm using LibreOffice version 4.2.8.2

Comment: I am using version 7. If possible, try updating your version.